# Multivariable derivative of matrix valued function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Determine the derviative of
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n, n} , \quad 
> \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}
>   \alpha(\mathbf{x}) & 1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0
>   \\
>   1 & \alpha(\mathbf{x}) & 1  & 0 & \cdots & 0
>   \\
>   0 &  1 & \alpha(\mathbf{x}) & 1  & \cdots & 0
>   \\
>   \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
>   \\
>   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \alpha(\mathbf{x})& 1 
>   \\
>   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \alpha(\mathbf{x})
> \end{bmatrix} 
> \end{align*}
> whereby $\alpha(\mathbf{x})\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}  \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function.

**My attempt:**
I tried to determine the derivative using the chain rule, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \left \{x \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
 x & 1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  1 & x & 1  & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  0 &  1 &x & 1  & \cdots & 0
  \\
  \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x& 1 
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x 
\end{bmatrix}\right\} \circ \alpha(\mathbf{x})
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{D}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})h
= \mathbf{I}_{n} \cdot \mathrm{D}\alpha(\mathbf{x})h
.\end{align*}
However, this would suggest that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{D}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{I}_{n} \cdot \mathrm{D}\alpha(\mathbf{x})
\end{align*}
which makes little sense to me since
$\mathrm{D}\alpha(\mathbf{x})$ is a row vector (for some fixed $\mathbf{x}$), making it not compatible with
$\mathbf{I}_{n}$ (the $n \times n $ identity matrix). Where is my mistake?

**Edit:**
For the first map, call it $f(x)$,  I calculated:
\begin{align*}
  f(x + h) &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 x + h & 1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  1 & x  + h& 1  & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  0 &  1 &x + h & 1  & \cdots & 0
  \\
  \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x + h& 1 
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x  + h
\end{bmatrix}
 \\
&= 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
 x & 1 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  1 & x & 1  & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  0 &  1 &x & 1  & \cdots & 0
  \\
  \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x& 1 
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &x 
\end{bmatrix}}_{f(x)} 
+ \underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix}
 h & 0 & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  0 & h & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \\
  0 &  0 &h & 0  & \cdots & 0
  \\
  \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &h& 0
  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &h 
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{I}_{n}h}
\end{align*}
so when plugging this into the definition of the derivative
I get
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{h \to 0} 
  \frac{\left\|f(x + h) - f(x) - \mathrm{D}f(x)h\right\|_{2} }{h}= 
  \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\left\|\mathbf{I}_{n}h - \mathrm{D}f(x)h\right\|_{2} }{h} \stackrel{!}{=}  0
\end{align*}
from which I concluded $\mathrm{D}f(x) = \mathbf{I}_{n}$

Comment: Note that the derivative at $x$ will be a linear function from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^{n,n} = \mathbf{Mat}(n \times n),$ this is quite the expression (I believe this will be an $n \times n \times n$ "matrix"). You can, however, "identify" $A(x)$ with the sum of a constant matrix plus the diagonal matrix with entries $\alpha(x)$ (you already did this). The evaluation should be relatively obvious $A'(x) \cdot h$ will be the diagonal matrix with entries $\alpha'(x) \cdot h.$

Comment: While I have never work this way myself, I also believe that when you can "identify" $A(x) = M(x) \circ \alpha(x)$ then $A'(x) = M'(\alpha(x)) \otimes \alpha'(x)$ (where $\otimes$ is the tensor product of matrices). Try Neudecker and Magnus' Matrix Differential Calculus.

Comment: @Mason could you please point out my mistake?

Comment: Why not just write $A(x) =\alpha(x) I_n + const$?

Comment: @Laz yes, don't know why I didn't do that...

Comment: @Laz do you see where my mistake lays?

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct. $Df(x)$ is the map that sends $h \in \mathbb{R}$ to $hI_n$. So for $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $DA(x)y = (D\alpha(x)y) I_n$.

Comment: but the composition is $f(\alpha(\mathbf{x}))$ so shouldn't it be the other way around, i.e. $(\mathrm{D}f)(\alpha(\mathbf{x})) \cdot \mathrm{D}\alpha(\mathbf{x})\cdot h$?

Comment: do you know why the dimensions conflict?

Comment: @Richard there is no conflict. $DA(x) : \mathbb{R}^n \to M(n, \mathbb{R})$ just as $A$ does.